# PHP error_log() output sent all at once

Tags: php, apache, error-log

For the past 10 years or so, I have been using error_log() and as my PHP processes run, I would see and track progress by watching the error log. This still works fine locally as well.

Since starting up a new PHP 8 server, this no longer works. All of the output seems to be buffered and dropped at the end in one long log line. Which is not helpful at all.

Have I messed up, or missed a setting, in setting up my latest server that changed this behavior? It is a traditional LAMP stack.

Comment: Are you sending log data to dedicated files or to Apache log files? I can't speak for Linux, but my Windows development instances of Apache have not flushed log files in real time for many years (a performance optimisation, I'd guess). Also, what PHP SAPI are you using?

Comment: "dropped at the end in one long log line" - I think I missed this part... Is there a chance it's a file with Linux line feeds (LF) inspected with a Windows editor that expects CR+LF?

Comment: I am going to the default Apache log files and I am using FastCGI. I guess it's possible that this changed years ago and I have only noticed now with the update. Locally, where it still works on MAMP, it says I am using the Apache 2.0 handler. Is this something that would change based on wether I am using FastCGI, CLI, or mod_php?